# How do the Dallas movies fit between the old and new shows?

Tags: continuity, dallas

The [last episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conundrum_%28Dallas%29) of the original Dallas aired in 1991. Two reunion movies were made. The first, [J.R. Returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas%3a_J.R._Returns), aired in 1996. The second, [War of the Ewings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas%3a_War_of_the_Ewings), aired in 1998. The series was [revived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas_%282012_TV_series%29) in 2012.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas_%282012_TV_series%29#Continuity) that the 2012 series does not include the movies in its continuity. Is that accurate? Is there, in fact, no reference at all to the events of the two reunion movies? Does the new series actually *contradict* the movies?

Comment: Some constructive criticism: you're asking a few different questions here. One about continuity between an old project and a rebooted one, and another about viewing order/relevance. Also: the interview cited in that Wiki article answers your question about continuity, definitively, from a writer/executive producer for the show.

Comment: You're correct that I'm asking two questions. I've removed the second question. As for the producers' statement, I'm not particularly interested in official continuity policy. I'm interested in what's been executed, on screen, which may or may not match that stated policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The two movies are ignored in the continuity of the show.**

Cynthia Cidre, the new show's writer and executive producer, addressed this [in an interview](http://ultimatedallas.com/cynthiacidre/):

> **Interviewer**: In JR Returns the scene was set for a continuation of the Barnes Ewing
>   feud. Why did you move away from this?
>
> **Cynthia** - I was told, not necessarily to pick up where it left off but
>   not to pay to much attention to the movies because the movies had
>   tried to wrap stuff up in two hours. But we did not, I have to admit,
>   although I saw one of them, I did not download it in my brain. I was
>   really going off the end of the season, I don't pick it up from then,
>   its now 2012 so we have not seen the Ewing family in all those years
>   but now we are going to see them and they look good.

Therefore, the two movies were *not* considered canon. This can be seen in the treatment of JR. For example, in the first film it was revealed J.R. shot a mirror and left to go to Europe. In the second film, he returned and tried to regain his empire. **All** of this is ignored in the new series.

So the two Dallas movies have officially been [retconned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity) and are no longer canon.